# Data for Monte-Carlo simulation of evolution used in an article

Tags: data-request, biology

An open access article in BMC Bioinformatics entitled "[PhyloSim - Monte Carlo simulation of sequence evolution in the R statistical computing environment](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3102636)" (DOI: [10.1186/1471-2105-12-104](https://doi.org/10.1186/1471-2105-12-104)) refers to the results of a Monte-Carlo simulation. Can anybody help find the data from the article?

Comment: please summarize your request *in the body of your question*

Answer (score 2):

The paper links to the R package `PhyloSim` available at

https://cran.r-project.org/package=phylosim , which is hosted as an open source Github repository at

https://github.com/bsipos/phylosim/ .

The repository has a folder called "PAMLdat" among other potential data sources:

https://github.com/bsipos/phylosim/tree/master/PAMLdat

Comment: ,How to open ,dat files? is it for R, and is there script to reproduce example?

Comment: @psysky if you look at the links and read the answer you will see that, yes, it is for R. There is extensive documentation on the R project site about how to read .dat files.

Comment: @user02814, but where R script for this article?

Comment: the main github repo is filled with R scripts https://github.com/bsipos/phylosim/